# Multiple Scrollmagic scenes on fixed container

Tags: javascript, reload, scene, tween

I would like to know a simple way to just clear any previous `tweening` scene on page  reload on a fixed container.

You will see on the `codepen` after the second scene `Tgroupe` when you refresh the page the controller trigger both the scene.

Thanks

```
    [http://codepen.io/dominium/pen/peGOKG/]
```

Comment: Please include your code in the post. You can even make your HTML, CSS, JS right here in Stack Overflow. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers])

Comment: I have to go but I will check it out tomorrow. Look complicated when it's already in codepen.